# Custom Iterator with more than one return value

Tags: r, iterator

My custom iterator is a bit slow. I hope to get a speed up when I use the `unlist(as.list(ic, n=2000))` construct. However, I do not know how to implement this functionality. I only found the `nextElem` and `hasNext` methods. The iterator looks like this:

```
library(itertools)
fibonacci <- function(count = NA) {
    ab = c(0, 1)
    n <- function() {
      if (!is.na(count)) {
        if (count > 0) count <<- count -1
        else stop('StopIteration')
      }
      #
      ab <<- c(ab[2], sum(ab))
      ab[1]
    }
    obj <- list(nextElem = n)
    class(obj) <- c('fibonacci', 'abstractiter', 'iter')
    obj
}
```

I can use it like this:

```
ic <- fibonacci ()
print (nextElem (ic))
```

Now I would like to get the next 10 fibonacci numbers at once, via

```
print(unlist(as.list(ic, n=10)))
```

But this of course needs to be implemented. How would I do this?

The fibonacci iterator serves as an example. Actually, I work on an iterator that gives all k-combinations of an n-set, i.e. a memory-friendly version of `combn`.

Comment: You need to provide an explanation of what you are trying to achieve and an example of how the iterator is used. Also, your code needs comments.

Comment: What about `sapply(1:10,function(i) { ic$nextElem() })` ? (Voted to repon now you added more details)

Comment: I would like to avoid to call nextElem repeatedly, I hope for a speedup if I calculate in bulk. Thanks for your reopen vote!

Comment: @KarstenW. Then I don't think an iterator is the proper way to go, a recursive function to return a vector may be a better approach. All in all you'll always have to call it repeatedly or you won't get the values ...

Comment: I think your actual problem would make a better example since I can understand what you'd like to achieve with it.